# How to prevent to assign undefined value in place of default value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to print first and the last name of a string in my function but if any of parameter is undefined then it prints undefined but I want to use default value instead. I want to accomplish this by using es6/es7 features and here is my efforts:

```
const printName =  (name = { first: 'K', last: 'M', separator: ' '}) =>  {
    console.log("name", name);
    let {first, last} = name;
    fullname = `${first}${seprator}${last}`;
    return fullName;
}
```

Now

```
let param = {first: 'A', last: undefined};
printName(param); // desired output 'A M'
let param = {first: undefined, last: 'B'};
getName(param) //desired output 'K B'
```

If the user forgot to send any of param than it should print 'K M'

I want to use ES6 features like rest/spread operator and Object.assign in the proper way but fail to achieve the desired output

Comment: Hey dude, I've offered a couple of solutions on how to make your code work. Please find my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several typos and syntax errors in your code. Your typos were the `separator` in your `fullName` instantiation and your last function call was to `getName` (I assumed you meant `printName`). Your syntax errors are as follows: You need to instantiate `fullName` before you use it; Also, best practice is to set you're default parameters one at a time rather than in an object, then set your params in an array rather than an object and use the spread `...` operator to pass them into your function.

The last thing is your use of `let`. You should only be using this if you intend on changing the value of the variable. This tells the developer that the variable will change over time. As opposed to `const` which is used to tell the developer that the value of the variable is a constant for the variable's lifetime (hence the name const).

Try the following code snippet:

```js
const printName =  (first = 'K', last = 'M', separator = ' ') =>  {
    const fullName = `${first}${separator}${last}`;
    return fullName;
}

let param = ['A', undefined];
console.log(printName(...param)); // desired output 'A M'
param = [undefined, 'B'];
console.log(printName(...param)); //desired output 'K B'
```

If for some reason, you must pass your parameters as an object you can do it like this:

```js
const printName =  ({first = 'K', last = 'M'}, separator = ' ') =>  {
    const fullName = `${first}${separator}${last}`;
    return fullName;
}

let param = {first: 'A', last: undefined};
console.log(printName(param)); // desired output 'A M'
param = {first: undefined, last: 'B'};
console.log(printName(param)); //desired output 'K B'
```

Comment: Thanks. sometimes I send different separator that's why I want it in same object

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Tyou are assigning the new values to the variables. Try this.


const printName =  ({first='A',last='M',seprator=' '}) =>  {
    let fullName = `${first}${seprator}${last}`;
    return fullName;
}
let param = {first: 'B',last:'X'};
console.log(printName(param));
```